# Pass AWS role supplied credentials to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I am trying to run docker-container that has aws cli and cfdeployment installed. I am trying to run the docker container on my local machine. I have an AWS profile set up locally in ~/.aws/config file

```
[profile dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::****:role/test-deploy-role
source_profile = default
```

I need to use the temporary credentials supplied by this role inside the docker container to execute a CF template.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM docker:17.04.0-ce

RUN apk update && apk add python && apk add py-pip && apk add bash

RUN pip install pip --upgrade && pip install setuptools --upgrade && pip install awscli && pip install cfdeployment==0.2.3 --extra-index-url https://dn2h7gel4xith.cloudfront.net

ADD test.sh /root/test.sh

VOLUME /tmp/work
VOLUME /root/.aws


ENTRYPOINT ["/root/test.sh", "cfdeployment"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Mount the `/root/.aws` folder when running the container:

```
docker run -v /root/.aws:/root/.aws ...
```

This will make both host and container share the same folder.

Comment: I did this.  Its still using my IAM user credentials and not picking up the role credentials from the `[profile dev]`. How do I set which profile to use in the `docker run` command?

Comment: I know we can export env variable using `docker run -e`. But is it possible to do some thing like this from docker run? `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile dev)`

Comment: Check your host and container user's home directory. In my case `-v ~/.aws:/usr/sbin/.aws` worked